# Как принять this в функцию

Tags: javascript

```
onclick="color(this)"

function color(el) {
   $(el).css('background','red !important');
}
```

В чем ошибка? Цвет не меняется

Comment: `onclick="color(this)"

function color(el) {
  obj=$(el);
  obj.css('background','red !important');
}` ?

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, 
'function color(el) {
  obj=el; 
 $(obj).css('background','red !important');
}'
'onclick="color(this)'
Не работает

Comment: `obj=$(el)` ......либо сразу `$(el).css('background','red !important');`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
Не получается
`function color(el) {
  $(el).css('background','red !important');
}`
`onclick="color(this)"`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r37021Ln/  ....... зачем вы меняете код вопроса  одного на второй на третий? ведь то, что сейчас в вопросе - должно работать....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский http://stretch-ceilings.by/ При клике на заголовок статьи не срабатывает смена цвета

Comment: @идентикон - в странице нет кода с функцией `color`

Comment: @igor А сейчас есть? Все равно не работает

Comment: @igor Я даже на страницу его вынес

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я меняю потому что это правильно решение но оно все равно не работает

Comment: `$(el).css('background','red !important');` да дейсвительно применив !important цвет вообще не меняется. Хотя если изначально прописать css свойство `background` с `red !important` то всё ок.

Comment: @jekaby Огромное спасибо, сработало

Comment: @идентикон у вас изначально ошибка совсем в другом была и смысл вопроса совсем в другом был..., совсем не тот, что сейчас....И даже заголовок говорит о другой проблеме.. Нельзя писать "почему у меня ботинки изнашиваются", а в процессе получить вопрос "почему торт без вишни". умейте как минимум ставить вопрос корректно, иначе вы только всех сбиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавлять класс попробовать тогда, на который повесить `background:red !important;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/r37021Ln/1/

css:

```
.red {
  background:red !important;
}
```

js:

```
function color(el) {
       $(el).addClass('red');
}
```